# Install Google Chrome in CentOS

Tags: centos, software-installation, yum, chrome

I run a CentOS 6.3 version of 32 bit VM in the Mac OS machine. I get these info from the terminal,

```
$ uname -a 
Linux Cloudera-Training-VM-4.1.1.c 2.6.32-279.14.1.el6.i686 #1 SMP Tue Nov 6 21:05:14 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

$ uname -i
i386

$ cat /etc/issue

CentOS release 6.3 (Final)
Kernel \r on an \m
```

I would like to install Google Chrome in the VM and I read the instructions from a [webpage](https://www.hiroom2.com/2017/08/12/centos-7-google-chrome-en/):

It informs to run the following commands:

```
$ URL=https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm

$ sudo yum install -y ${URL}
```

Later to launch the Google Chrome from the terminal,

```
$ google-chrome-stable
```

When I run the `sudo yum install -y ${URL}` command, I get the output provided below,

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.dhakacom.com
 * extras: mirror.dhakacom.com
 * updates: mirror.dhakacom.com
http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/rpm/stable/i386/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404"
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: google-chrome. Please verify its path and try again
```

What is the issue here and how to solve it?

Comment: Further reading: https://askubuntu.com/a/724170/436624

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ```
> $ uname -i
> i386
> ```

This is a 32-bit system. 32-bit Google Chrome is not updated anymore.

> ```
> URL=https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm
> ```

This is a 64-bit package.

### Alternative Option

[Vivaldi browser](https://vivaldi.com/download/?lang=en_US), relatively new browser, but still regularly updated for 32-bit

Comment: I reckon Chromium (compiled or from repos) could still be available.